# Calling a method inside while loop (if/else)

Tags: c#, oop

I have 3 predefined methods. Out of 3 methods one method should be called inside the while loop and the conditions are pre known. As per my experience, There are two chances to call the methods.

1. I have to make the decision inside while loop by using if and else condition
2. Having 3 separate methods and call it before while loop

What I think is, in the first chance if I make the decision inside, it is time consuming because it has to decide every time which method to call. Is the second chance against OOP principle because except while loop decision making all other things are same. so is it worth to create 3 methods?

Edit:::::

I used some performance profilers and optimised my answer

Comment: Favor readability over performance. _Premature optimisation_ is indeed a thing.. and worrying about this level of performance is definitely demonstrating it.

Comment: Have you profiled? Is one method actually causing a measurable performance difference in your application? "Is it worth it?" is a question that only you can answer.

Comment: Agree with Simon. *Get it working* first. Then *profile* your application to see where the bottlenecks are (Hint: it's not where you're looking right now). And only then should you make optimizations.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, All three methods contains seperate algorithms and it runs for miniutes. Yes I will profile it first and see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some people have already pointed out in comments, you should just get your code working, without worrying about performance at this stage.

However, ***if*** performance turns out to be an issue, you should *profile* your application, to find out where the issues are occurring.

[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) for a nice tutorial on Profiling.